# How can I speed up a Silverlight scroll viewer?

Tags: silverlight, scrollviewer

I have a `ScrollViewer` in my Silverlight client that shows lists of items in a selected category. The items change size when selected. Under normal circumstances the `ScrollViewer` works fine, but one category has nearly 300 items. When this category is selected the `ScrollViewer` is nearly impossible to use. Is it rendering everything in the list? Is there a way I can speed it up?

Comment: i Think It Should Help You :- http://www.kirupa.com/net/ui_virtualization_pg1.htm

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that might help:

```
<!-- This needs to be contained in a parent panel like a grid -->
<ListBox x:Name="Items" >
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate> <!-- Broke it out to allow resizing -->
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsPresenter/> <!-- This little fella does magical things -->            
            </ScrollViewer>         
        </ControlTemplate>      
    </ListBox.Template>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>  <!-- Recycle was a must -->        
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>       
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <HyperlinkButton  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5" />
                <!-- This guy I did need to set a minwidth on to retain nice and predictable scrolling  when datacontext was potentially changing -->
                <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" MinWidth="1160" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>         
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>           
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Please try to write actual answers instead of just linking.